# Google data studio (convert a null value to 0)

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to change a null value to 0 to display phone conversions with days in a Bar chart.

That means, if I don't have a phone conversion in a day, the value will be 0.

But nothing works, if I don't have phone conversion the value becomes null.

Can you help me?

I used:
CASE WHEN  IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  END

and:
NARY_MAX (,0)

[image: Text]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So `NARY_MAX(<field/metric>,0)` has been working for me in the past to use fields / metrics that can potentially be `null` in a calculation. Suddenly it  stopped working, no idea why.

What seems to work, however, is `IFNULL(<field/metric>,0)`.

Answer (score -1):

not sure what your data source is, but if it is in excel or google sheets I would write a quick IF function to use as the data reference

say you have the values in column A, in column B write =IF(A2="",0,A2)